# Android 8.0.0 settings remove suggestion

Tags: settings, 8.0-oreo

I am using Nokia 3 with Android 8.0.0. Whenever I open settings option, suggestion option display first, so every time I have to swipe and remove it. Is there any settings, that removes suggestion in settings option.

[image]

Please check screenshot and see what am I want. I am asking about in Settings App, not about top of menu which shows most used app.

Comment: what will happen if you tap on up arrow near the text named "suggestions". Is the same item repeated again? Otherwise go to that settings, once by tapping on "On body detection". May be it will not show again.

Comment: on arrow tap, suggestion collapse highlighted options. I had to swipe to remove  highlighed options to remove suggestion. but after some time it comes again.!

Comment: One method described here, please go through : https://forum.xda-developers.com/nook-tablet/help/off-suggestions-settings-nougat-t3603249

Comment: Thanks @RahulGopi . I  will try it but need some time to reappear. I just swiped.

Comment: Related and unanswered: [How to disable dashboard summary in Settings app?](//android.stackexchange.com/q/185323)